# Laravel eloquent problem with model __construct()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, mass-assignment

I have a model called Application with construct() method inside it and i add $fillable to my model. I know that i should not use Application::create() for mass assignment and use new Application instead but my question is why i am getting null result from eloquent first() when i call eloquent search with where()?

here is my model

```
protected $guarded = ['id'];
protected $fillable = ['size','status','packagename','title','type','version','port','mouse','keyboard','game','cms_user_id','url'];

public function __construct( $value = NULL, array $attributes = array() )
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

and i have this line in my controller returns null

```
$application = Application::where('packagename',$request->packagename)->first();
```

Comment: could you provide use with you table structure ?

Comment: btw, the constructor for the model has to take the `attributes` as the first argument if you want it to function properly ... numerous things will construct models by passing attributes to their constructor ... and there is nothing wrong with using the `create` method to create and persist a model